# Analysis Bootstrapper for Visual Studio Projects Plugin without FxCop

Tags: resharper, sonarqube, fxcop

Looking to set up a sonar C# project with the Resharper command line tool. Wondering is it possible to run Analysis Bootstrapper for Visual Studio without FxCop and Stylecop?